# how can I get the fourier transform of this generalized function?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

when function f(x) of the generalized function is $f(x) = x+2$, the fourier transform of the generalized function will be like   ($F$ is the Fourier transform)
$$\int_{-∞}^{∞}(x+2)(F[k(x)])dx$$
when $f(x) = \sin x$, it will be
$$\int_{-∞}^{∞}\sin x(F[k(x)])dx$$
Is there a way to simplify these?
For example, I know when $f(x) = 1$, It will be
$$\int_{-∞}^{∞}1(F[k(x)])dx = \int_{-∞}^{∞}e^{i0x}(F[k(x)])dx = 2πk(0)$$
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is $k(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $g$ a Schwartz function and $F(g)$ its Fourier transform then the Fourier transform of $x+2$ **in the sense of distributions** is the unique distribution $T$ such that for all $g$ Schwartz $$\langle T,g\rangle = \langle x+2,F(g)\rangle$$
where $\langle x+2,F(g)\rangle$ means the Riemann integral $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty (x+2) F(g)(x)dx$ because $x+2$ is a continuous function.

The Fourier inversion theorem for Schwartz functions yields
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty 2 F(g)(x)dx= 4\pi g(0)$$ and
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty x F(g)(x)dx= \int_{-\infty}^\infty (-i) F(g')(x)dx = -2i\pi g'(0)$$
thus $$T = 4\pi\delta+2i\pi \delta'$$